# Avoid $rootScope.$on — it risks memory leaks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

### Angularjs: Subscribing to a Service event in Directive doesn't update

I am trying to `$emit`/`$broadcast` an event in a Service and subscribe to it inside a Directive but it is not being fired.

In this case I try both `$emit` and `$broadcast` but although both are seen in the controller, neither are seen in the directive.

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

```
angular.module('my_app', [])

.service('my_service', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    this.do_something = () => {
        $rootScope.$emit('myEvent');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent');
    }
}])

.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        scope: {
            some_var: '@?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $rootScope.$on('myEvent', ()=>{
                console.log('event fired in directive');
            })
        }
    }
}])

.controller('my_controller', ['$rootScope', 'my_service', function($rootScope, my_service) {
    $rootScope.$on('myEvent', ()=>{
        console.log('event fired in controller');
    })

    my_service.do_something();

}])
```

And the html:

```
<my-directive ng-if="some_expression"></my-directive>
```

In this case I only get:

```
event fired in controller
event fired in controller
```

Comment: The directive has an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid `$rootScope.$on` — it risks memory leaks

In the course of its operation, AngularJS adds and removes DOM with their attached directives and controllers. The listener functions added by [`$rootScope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) are not automatically removed when a directive or controller is removed. This can result in memory leaks and undesired behavior.

**To avoid memory leaks,** add event listeners to the `$scope` of the controller, not `$rootScope`:

```
.controller('my_controller', ['$scope', 'my_app_service', function($scope, my_app_service) {
    $scope.$on('myEvent', ()=>{
        console.log('event fired in controller');
    }
    my_app_service.do_something();    
}])
```

With directives, add event listeners in the linking function:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    }
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {    
        scope.$on('myEvent', ()=>{
            console.log('event fired in directive');
        });
    }
})
```

From the Docs:

> ## Scope Events Propagation
>
> Scopes can propagate events in similar fashion to DOM events. The event can be [broadcasted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to the scope children or [emitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to scope parents.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

---

## Update

> *I corrected my question as I do actually have the event listener in the linking function. But still not working.*

Be sure that the name of the directive is in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) in the JavaScript:

```
.̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶(̶'̶m̶y̶_̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶'̶,̶ ̶[̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
.directive('myDirective', [function() {
   // ...
}])
```

And [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) in the HTML:

```
<my-directive>
</my-directive>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I corrected my question as I do actually have the event listener in the linking function.

Comment: It is quite common for directives to silently fail to instantiate due to typos in either the JavaScript or the HTML. Check to see if the directive instantiates by putting a `console.log` in the directive construction function.

Comment: Oh man! You are correct. It wasn't instantiating. But it was because I had an `ng-if` when using my directive. `<my-directive ng-if="some_expression"></my-directive>`. Switched it to an ng-show and all is working. Thanks for the info and the push in the right direction.